# Excel VBA: Copy data from multiple passwordprotected workbooks in a folder into one worksheet in another workboo

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code that opens a password protected workbook in a folder, copy some values out of it and paste the values in active woorkbook. This works fine.

My problem is that I have 16 password protected files in this folder, and I need a loop that does the same thing with every file. Below you can find the code, and I think all my problems should be properly explained with comments inside the code. Please ask if anything is unclear. In advance, thanks for any help!

Code:

```
Sub Bengt()
Dim sPath As String
Dim vFolder As Variant
Dim sFile As String
Dim sDataRange As String
Dim mydata As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WBookOther As Workbook
Dim myArray As Variant  '<<does the list of passwords have to be array?


sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
sDataRange = "Budsjett_resultat'!E2"  '<<every file I want to open has data in this sheet and range
sFile = "BENGT.xlsm"  '<< how to make sFile be every file in folder?


' here I want a loop that opens every woorkbook in the folder M::\SALG\2016\Budsjett\

Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile, Password:="bengt123")
' all passwords starts with filename + three numbers after as you can see
' here I want to make excel find the password out of a list of passwords in range B100:B116
mydata = "='" & sPath & "[" & sFile & "]" & sDataRange

'mydata = "='M:\SALG\2016\Budsjett\Bengt.xlsmBudsjett_resultat'!E2:E54" '<< change as required

'link to worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("T2:T54")
'in this case I want the loop to find "BENGT"(which is the filename) in cell T1, and paste the values in range T2:T54.
'For the other files, I want the loop to find the filename (of the file it opened) in row 1,
'and paste the values in range ?2-?54 at the column with the same name as the filename
.Formula = mydata
.Value = .Value
WBookOther.Close SaveChanges:=False

End With

End Sub
```

For the password array I have tried following code:

```
Sub passord()
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B100:B116")
On Error Resume Next  'turn error reporting off
For i = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("M:\SALG\2016\Budsjett\BENGT.xlsm", Password:=myArray(i, 1))
If Not wb Is Nothing Then bOpen = True: Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

- I have tried to implement the last sub into the first sub, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Instead of opening it with password you can open it as read only try this Workbooks.Open Filename:=file-path, ReadOnly:=True